# Removed old interactions in outputted pact json file

Tags: pact

I've managed to get pact contract testing working and it outputs the json file. But it has previous interactions in the json file when I was testing how do I remove all previous interactions from the json file. Is there a setting ?

I have tried deleting and running the tests again but it still populates interactions that no longer exist.

I have implemented asp.net core version of Pact.

https://github.com/tdshipley/pact-workshop-dotnet-core-v1

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the underlying Mock Server is not being shut down correctly, and is thus still serialising pacts from previous (successful) test runs.

Might be worth checking to see that there are no existing processes still hanging around after the tests have been run - it should run a clean mock server each time.

Comment: That is indeed the issue. @user2956121 it might not be obvious from the processes running but most likely, if you see a ruby.exe hanging around that's the Pact mock server wandering where it shouldn't be! Thanks Matthew!